# How to get object that does not have valid field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get valid and invalid array out from my `data` , How do we use filter  to do both operations provide validArray that matches the condition and vice versa.

data

```
   const misMatchedItems = [];
      const matchedItems = [];
       const rxInfos=  [{
                "drugName": "ATRIPLA TABS",
                "ancillaryProductInd": "false",
                "firstFillIndicator": "N",
                "indexId": "1",
                "uniqueRxId": "1711511459709"
            },
            {
                "errorDetails": {
                    "errorCode": "0077",
                    "errorDesc": "uniqueRxId not found for2711511911555"
                }
            }
        ]

    const validArray = rxInfos.filter((element) => {
                    return (element.hasOwnProperty('indexId'));
                });
    matchedItems = validArray;
    const inValidArray = rxInfos.filter((element) => {
                    return (element.hasOwnProperty(!'indexId'));
                });

    misMatchedItems = inValidArray;
```

Comment: You probably need something like this `return !(element.hasOwnProperty('indexId'));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the negation(exclamation point) in the wrong spot. I believe this should work:

```
const inValidArray = rxInfos.filter((element) => {
            return !(element.hasOwnProperty('indexId'));
        });
```

You could also perform both actions in one pass:

```
const validArray = [];
const invalidArray = [];

rxInfos.forEach(function(element) {
   if (element.hasOwnProperty('indexId')) {
       validArray.push(element);
   } else {
       invalidArray.push(element);
   }
});
```

Comment: is there way to do better instead of running filter twice ?

Comment: Sure! Updated original answer.

Answer (score 2):

This uses [destructuring assigment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve your goal.

```
const [misMatchedItems, matchedItems] = (rxInfos.reduce((rxInfosSeparated, item) => {
  rxInfosSeparated[item.hasOwnProperty('indexId') ? 1 : 0].push(item);
  return rxInfosSeparated
}, [[] , []]));
```

```js
const rxInfos=  [{
  "drugName": "ATRIPLA TABS",
  "ancillaryProductInd": "false",
  "firstFillIndicator": "N",
  "indexId": "1",
  "uniqueRxId": "1711511459709"
},
{
  "errorDetails": {
      "errorCode": "0077",
      "errorDesc": "uniqueRxId not found for 2711511911555"
  }
},
{
  "errorDetails": {
      "errorCode": "0078",
      "errorDesc": "uniqueRxId not found for 2711511911556"
  }
},
{
  "drugName": "ATRIPLA CAPSULES",
  "ancillaryProductInd": "false",
  "firstFillIndicator": "N",
  "indexId": "2",
  "uniqueRxId": "1711511459708"
}]

const [misMatchedItems, matchedItems] = (rxInfos.reduce((rxInfos, item) => {
  rxInfos[item.hasOwnProperty('indexId') ? 1 : 0].push(item);
  return rxInfos
}, [[] , []]));

console.log(misMatchedItems);
console.log(matchedItems);
```